# PHPSpec: How to handle data heavy mocks in spec?

Tags: php-7, phpspec

I have a series of specs that are doing what I would like them to but I'm wondering if I'm overcomplicating things as my let function for some of them is rather large and cumbersome.

I have built specs for a series of classes that process responses from SQL or JSON API depending on the response. The specs are just checking the resultant object of the processes of each class. I've mocked the connection to return valid mock data for each type of request that the specs would trigger. I'm trying to think of a better way to provide this mock data than having rather large arrays and JSON strings just sitting in the spec files.

For example (simplified):

```
class CharacterProcessorSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
  public function let(AdapterInterface $adapter)
  {
    $characters = [
      [
        'name' => 'Timmy',
        'class' => 'Fighter',
        'level' => 1,
        'race' => 'Elf',
        'str' => 16,
        'dex' => 14,
        'con' => 18,
        'int' => 10,
        'wis' => 12,
        'cha' => 11,
        ... // Rest of the minimally required fields
      ], [
        ... // Second character for processing multiple at once
      ]
    ];
    $adapter->fetch(new CharacterRequest('Timmy'))->willReturn([$characters[0]]);
    $adapter->fetch(new CharacterRequest('*'))->willReturn($characters);
    $this->beConstructedWith($adapter);
  }

  public function it_should_build_requested_character_details()
  {
    $this->build('Timmy')->shouldReturnArrayOfCharacters();
  }

  public function it_should_build_all_character_details()
  {
    $this->buildAll()->shouldReturnArrayOfCharacters();
  }

  public function getMatchers()
  {
    return [
      'returnArrayOfCharacters' => function($characters) {
        foreach ($characters as $c) {
          if (!$c instanceof Character) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Is it worth me moving the arrays to a separate file and loading them in or is that a no no?

Note: The build functions are designed to not care if the adapter is for SQL or the API, it just converts the data into a consistant object. Therefore the spec does not actually define what the data is (in the example I have provided it's the same as an SQL response but I usually have the second entry formatted how the JSON response would be as it processes on a per entry basis).

Comment: Arrange part of a test (independently of the library you're using) could be cumbersome sometimes. If you need as "fixture" all those chars in the array I'm afraid that this is the "minimum setup" for your test so you cannot act differently. One solution is to reduce that array to a minimum set of "significant" data and move over. I'm not 100% sure if this comment is ok or not, but in my experience, I always act like this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it worth me moving the arrays to a separate file and loading them in or is that a no no?

No, is not worth this effort. You provide only data to constructor and with that it should be OK in direct definitions.